# Symfony2 and Doctrine2 : Use a Repository class result in Type class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have 5 Entities:

1. Affiliation
2. Person
3. User
4. UserAffiliation
5. PersonAffiliation

My goal is to display a list of choice fields where I can choose all the UserAffiliations which are not in PersonAffiliations.

My idea is to create a public function in the UserAffiliationRepository which will return only those affiliations for a specific user which are not preset for a specific person.

For that, I am using:

```
class UserAffiliationRepository extends EntityRepository
{ 
   public function getUnselectedAffiliations( $user_id = null, $person_id = null )
   {
      $commQB = $this->createQueryBuilder( 'ua' )
      ->select('ua');

      $commQB->where("ua.user_id = {$user_id}");

      $commQB->andWhere( "ua.affiliation_id not in ( select pa.affiliation_id  FROM SciForumVersion2Bundle:PersonAffiliation pa where pa.person_id = 3077 )" );

      return $commQB->getQuery()->getResult();
   }
}
```

And this works fine.

Now, I would like to use this result in a FormBuilder. For that, In my controller, I am using:

```
$affiliations = $em->getRepository('SciForumVersion2Bundle:UserAffiliation')->getUnselectedAffiliations($user->getId(), $author->getId())
$enquiry    = new PersonAffiliation();
$formType   = new SubmissionAffiliationAddFormType($user, $affiliations);
$form   = $this->createForm($formType, $enquiry);
```

And then in the Form class, I am using:

```
$builder->add('affiliation', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'SciForumVersion2Bundle:UserAffiliation',
            'multiple' => true));
```

But here, I am getting all the affiliations for the specific user, not only thos ones which are not allready in the PersonAffiliations entity.

Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to migrate your `getUnselectedAffiliations` function directly into entity_type in the following way

```
$builder->add('affiliation', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'SciForumVersion2Bundle:UserAffiliation',
            'multiple' => true,
            'query_builder' = function(EntityRepository $repo) use ($yourParameters){
                               return $repo->createQueryBuilder(....);}));
```

if you want to pass `$yourParameters`, you have to do that into `__construct` function (implement it, if you don't have one) and when you create your form, you can pass them along the calls

Comment: Thank you @DonCallisto. Yes, I have the _construct function and I am able to get all the needed parameters. I will try your solution right now.

Comment: Hm, first problem, how to access the `getUnselectedAffiliations ` in the entity_type class ? What should i put in createQueryBuilder(....)  Thank you

Comment: @Milos you don't ave to access it directly into the entity_type: you have to move the code you have into that function to `createQuerybuilder(....)` [replace the dots]

Comment: ah ok, and it is not possible to access the query from the repository directly  in the entity type?

Comment: @Milos I ignore that possibility. I suppose that if tutorials says that you have to write DQL or build a QueryBuilder directly into your entity_type, maybe this is the only and best solution. But I can't bet on it :) (have you to reuse this piece of code elsewhere?)

Comment: Thanks. I will then move the code in the entity_type class. For the moment, no, i do not have to reuse this code anywere but I though that maybe in the future I will, that's why I started by putting this in the repository. I will try your solution and if it will work, I will accept the answer, if not, I will come back to you soon.